# Why is ip defaulting to tap0 interface

Tags: networking, bridge, iproute2

I am trying to configure a few interfaces on my network. I have created tap0 for my VBox VMs and set enp6s0 (my Ethernet connection) to manual. I would like for my host to connect via br0 which is why I set inet to dhcp instead of manuel. However seemingly randomly my host will connect to the network via the tap0 interface (i.e. i have to ssh into the machine from the tap0 ip address). How can I set my host to only connect via br0?

Network Interfaces:

```
#cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet manual
    up ip link set enp6s0 up

auto tap0
iface tap0 inet manual
    up ip tuntap add mode tap tap0
    up ip link set tap0 up

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge-ifaces enp6s0 tap0
    bridge-ports enp6s0 tap0
    post-up ip link set br0 address 88:d7:f6:ae:7a:06
```

IP Link:

```
#ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 88:d7:f6:ae:7a:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 88:d7:f6:ae:7a:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 88:d7:f6:ae:7a:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:7b:48:57:39:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: vethM7FNJI@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:4a:c9:02:70:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
9: vethTJ3ADT@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:e6:ff:66:ef:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
11: vethJ5N8T3@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:bf:10:b5:0b:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
```

I am a networking newb and this configuration is pieced together from a few sources so if you see anything bizarre let me know. I am surprised that the tap0 interface state is DOWN:

```
5: tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:7b:48:57:39:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

given the /etc/network/interfaces settings:

```
up ip link set tap0 up
```

Especially given that this interface is being used to connect. How can I favor br0 over tap0 for my host?

Thanks :)

Comment: `i have to ssh into the machine from the tap0 ip address` So tap0 has an IP assigned? If so, do the VMs not work otherwise? Also where are you ssh'ing from? The Internet? A VM? The host itself?

Comment: You should really show `ip a` and `ip r` outputs.